# Why is there no water in the kitchen?

Tags: water

There is no water flow hot or cold in kitchen.  It works everywhere else in the house. The temperature has been between 0-20 in Northern VA.

Comment: Maybe the pipes are frozen? There's not a lot of info to go on here. Are the pipes on an outside wall? Do you have access to them?

Comment: Without knowing the layout of the pipes in your house there is not much someone can do. If it is due to freezing, do a web search to find the procedures for dealing with frozen water lines.